sent usdt to sol by mistake from stake.com
I stupidly sent my profits from stake.com from usdt to sol and I of course didnt receive it. I checked on solscan and it says completed, but since I gave the sol receiving code it didnt arrive to my account. There is only one transaction on the id which is mentioned on solscan which is the one i did. Is there anything I can do?

Unless you can get the private key for the recipient, there's no way to recover the funds unfortunately
